# QtableView Frozen column

Tags: python, pyqt

The directory  PyQt5-5.15.4\examples\itemviews\frozencolumn has an example of  QTableView that freezes column one.  A QTableview that does not scroll column one horizontally.  Two QTableView tables use the same QAbstractTableModel one table has all column disabled but column one and is placed on top of the other table.  The scrollbars for both tablesviews are tied together.  When the window is resized so that the last row is in view or larger.  The table with the frozen column one gets resized in height to the size of the viewport it should be resized in height to match the table with the other columns.  The frame of column one is extended to the bottom of the window. Calling height() on the table does not as one might expect return the height of the table but the height of the window.

```
def updateFrozenTableGeometry(self):
    self.frozenTableView.setGeometry(
        self.verticalHeader().width() + self.frameWidth(),
        self.frameWidth(), self.columnWidth(0),
        self.viewport().height() + self.horizontalHeader().height())
```

One can call rowAt(self.height()) and note the height when -1 is returned from rowAt.  The question is how to determine the height of the tableview when the table is shorter than the window that it is in.

All the examples of frozen column that I have found are based on this example, that is also in Qt examples.  Seems like there should be other approaches.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `self.height()` returns the size of the main table (including its scrollbars), and it's *not* the height of the window. When are you trying to call `self.height()`? Also, if you're using a container and call `self.height()` from there (`self` is the container), you will get the height of the container, not of the table.

Comment: The frozen column **and** the main table are both extended to the full height of the viewport. I think the [different colour applied to the frozen column in the example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-frozencolumn-example.html) is confusing you. The blank areas round the edge are also part of the table. You can easily prove this by resizing the last row to fill the empty space. What you're really asking for is the total height of all the *rows*, rather than the table (which clearly won't always be the same, whether there's a frozen column or not).